# перевод цвета в %RGB

Tags: javascript

День добрый, подскажите как сделать преобразование цвета из 0Xffb200 в % RGB.

Comment: ответ на en.so [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb)

Comment: Везде дают совет как перевести в шестнадцатеричную систему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const hex_color = 0Xffb200;

let r = hex_color >> 16;
let g = (hex_color & 0Xff00) >> 8;
let b = hex_color & 0Xff;

//rgb 0-255
console.log(r, g, b);
// Проценты:
console.log(r*100/256, g*100/256, b*100/256);
```

Comment: делить на `0Xffff`? не на `0X10000`? В JS нету оператора `>>`?

Comment: Я спрашиваю почему на 0xFFFF, а не на 0x10000? У вас получаются дробные значения там, где их быть не должно.

Comment: 0xFF - это не 100%? Как тогда получить 100?

Comment: @АндрейNOP 0XFF - это не 100%, это 256 в 16ричной системе. Получить 100 можете, если найдете подходящую вакансию и пройдете собеседование.

Answer (score 1):

Перевели HEX в RGB.

```js
hexDec("#ffb200");
 
function hexDec(h){
var m=h.slice(1).match(/.{2}/g);
m[0]=parseInt(m[0], 16);
m[1]=parseInt(m[1], 16);
m[2]=parseInt(m[2], 16);
console.log(m.join('.'));
console.log('R:'+m[0]*100/256+' G:'+m[1]*100/256+' B:'+m[2]*100/256);
 };
```